# Code to copy and paste range data based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to copy and paste a range of data if a certain condition is met in column "B" of the source range, but the code is omitting the condition and pasting all of the source range data. Can you help me understand why the code omitting the condition?

```
Sub CopyBasedOnCondition()
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    'Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim nRows As Integer
    
    ' Define your source and target ranges
    Set sourceRange = Worksheets("Historical State ICI Gr Rate").Range("A3:T559")
    Set targetRange = Worksheets("Very Small Systems").Range("A3:T559")
    
    ' Find the last row in the source range
    'lastRow = sourceRange.Rows.Count + sourceRange.Row - 1
    
    Set sht = Worksheets("Historical State ICI Gr Rate")
    nRows = Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in the source range
    For i = 1 To nRows
        ' Check if the value in column C meets your condition (e.g., "No")
        If sourceRange.Cells(i, 2).Value = 3840 Then
            ' Copy the corresponding cells from the source range to the target range
        targetRange.Value = sourceRange.Value
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Clear the clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: `targetRange.Value = sourceRange.Value` copies the entire range.  You are testing each row, but pasting the entire range each time.  You will need to paste the values row by row also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the comments which is marked with `**`.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CopyBasedOnCondition()
    Dim sourceSht As Worksheet
    Dim targetSht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim nRows As Long ' **
    ' ** Define your source and target sheet
    Set sourceSht = Worksheets("Historical State ICI Gr Rate")
    Set targetSht = Worksheets("Very Small Systems")
    ' Find the last row in the source range
    'lastRow = sourceRange.Rows.Count + sourceRange.Row - 1
    ' ** qualify Cells() with sourceSht
    nRows = sourceSht.Cells(sourceSht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Loop through each row in the source range
    ' ** Starts from row 3
    For i = 3 To nRows
        ' Check if the value in column C meets your condition (e.g., "No")
        ' ** Column C is (i, 3) instead of (i, 2)
        If sourceSht.Cells(i, 3).Value = 3840 Then
            ' Copy the corresponding cells from the source range to the target range
            ' **Copy A:T to the same row in targetSht
            targetSht.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 20).Value = sourceSht.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 20).Value
        End If
    Next i
    ' Clear the clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Based on Condition

[image]

**Usage**

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    CopyBasedOnCondition wb, "Historical State ICI Gr Rate", "A3:T3", _
        "Very Small Systems", "A3", 2, "=3840"
End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
Sub CopyBasedOnCondition( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal SourceSheetName As String, _
        ByVal SourceFirstRow As String, _
        ByVal DestinationSheetName As String, _
        ByVal DestinationFirstCell As String, _
        ByVal CriteriaColumnIndex As Long, _
        ByVal Condition As String)
    
    ' 1.) Read.
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SourceSheetName)
    
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    ' Reference the source range.
    With sws
        Dim LastRow As Long
        With .UsedRange
            LastRow = .Rows.Count + .Row - 1
        End With
        With .Range(SourceFirstRow)
            cCount = .Columns.Count
            If cCount < CriteriaColumnIndex Then Exit Sub ' not enough columns
            srCount = LastRow - .Row + 1
            If srCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
            Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
        End With
    End With
    
    ' For each match, return 1, otherwise 0,
    ' in the 2D one-based single-column Ones array.
    Dim scAddress As String: cAddress = srg.Columns(CriteriaColumnIndex).Address
    Dim Ones() As Variant: ' if match then 1 else 0:
    Ones = sws.Evaluate("IFERROR(--(" & cAddress & Condition & "),)")
    If Application.Sum(Ones) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no matches
    
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim Data() As Variant, sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long
    
    ' Return the values from the source range in the 2D one-based Data array.
    If srCount * cCount = 1 Then ' single cell
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1).Value = srg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        Data = srg.Value
    End If
    
    ' 2.) Modify.
    
    ' Using the information from the Ones array,
    ' return the matching values at the top of the Data array.
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If Ones(sr, 1) = 1 Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    ' 3.) Write.
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DestinationSheetName)
    ' Reference the destination range.
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = dws.Range(DestinationFirstCell)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    ' Return the values from the top of the Data array
    ' in the destination range...
    drg.Value = Data
    ' ... and clear below.
    drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).ClearContents
    
End Sub
```